# How can I write an efficient query to do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write an efficient query like the following

> "Get all rows that are deleted and that have no other row with the same value that are not-deleted"

Example.

```
| id | val   | deleted | 
========================
| 1  | "foo" |    1
------------------------
| 2  | "bar" |    1
------------------------
| 3  | "foo" |    0
------------------------
| 4  | "baz" |    1
------------------------
| 5  | "qux" |    0
------------------------
| 6  | "baz" |    1
------------------------
```

========>

```
------------------------
| 2  | "bar" |    1
------------------------
| 4  | "baz" |    1
------------------------
| 6  | "baz" |    1
------------------------
```

The reason why the rows with `foo` aren't in the result set is because one of them has `deleted = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this in two ways .

Your Data looks like :

```
SELECT * into #tab FROM(
VALUES(1,'foo',1),
(2,'bar',1),
(3,'foo',0),
(4,'baz',1),
(5,'qux',0),
(6,'baz',1)
) AS A (id,VAL,DELETED)
```

**Method 1 : Using Not Exists**

```
select * from #tab t
where DELETED=1 and 
not exists (select * from #tab t1 where t1.DELETED=0 and t1.VAL=t.val)
```

**Method 2 : Using Apply Operator**

```
SELECT T.* FROM #tab T
OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM #tab T1 WHERE T.VAL=T1.VAL AND T1.DELETED=0) as a 
where T.DELETED=1 AND A.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this query

```
select
    a.*
from
    myTable a
where
    not exists (
        select 1
        from mytable b
        where
            a.val = b.val
            and b.deleted = 0
    )
```

Here's one [article](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) you might be interested in

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the deleted values only not the others you could use `subquery` form where sub-query returns only the values which have been deleted with value of 1.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE val IN (
    SELECT val FROM table
    GROUP BY val
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT deleted) = 1 AND
           COUNT(DISTINCT case when deleted = 1 then deleted end) = 1
)
```

correlated sub-query might be useful

```
SELECT * FROM table t
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT val FROM table
        WHERE val = t.val
        GROUP BY val
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT deleted) = 1 AND
               COUNT(DISTINCT case when deleted = 1 then deleted end) = 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like me like join clauses this is an option : )

```
declare @t table(id int, val varchar(50) ,deleted bit) 
insert into @t(id,val,deleted)
values 
(1,'foo',1)
,(2,'bar',1)
,(3,'foo',0)
,(4,'baz',1)
,(5,'qux',0)
,(6,'baz',1)

select *
from @t t1
left join(select distinct t2t1.val from @t t2t1 where deleted=0) t2 on t1.val=t2.val
where t2.val is null
```